# Adding child to firebase (iOS) - inserting of new child doesn't stop

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I'm creating an app in which users can create and join events. I'm struggling with how to keep track of the events joined by the user. I've decided to store an array of 'event keys' (event IDs) for each user in Firebase. However, when the user taps the Join Event button, Firebase adds hundreds of new children (with the same event key) to an user. It looks like some kind of an infinite loop (but I'm not using any loops). First, I'm loading the current event keys array from Firebase and then I append the new one to the array. Then, the eventKeys child has to be updated.

```
@IBAction func joinEventButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    guard let uid = user?.uid else {
        return
    }

    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users").child(uid)

    ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        self.currentUser = CustomUser(snapshot: snapshot)

        if let currentUserEventKeys = self.currentUser?.eventKeys, let newEventKey = self.currentEvent?.key {
            var eventKeys: [String] = currentUserEventKeys
            eventKeys.append(newEventKey)
            let values = ["eventKeys": eventKeys]
            ref.updateChildValues(values)
        }
    }
}

var currentUser: CustomUser?
var currentEvent: CustomEvent?
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
```

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you are calling `ref.observe`, this is an open observation that once called, will forever observe that path in your database and execute the code inside it when a value is updated. As you’re updating the code inside it (updating a value), that also triggers the `ref.observe` (the open observation that’s always looking for values being updated), meaning it will also trigger the code inside, updating it again, creating that infinite loop. You’ll want to use Firebases `observeSingleEvent` instead